# Understanding the Use of "?" in Dart Function Parameters (bool?)

Tags: flutter, dart

During my exploration of Dart, I encountered the following code snippet in the Dart language tour (https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#functions):

```dart
/// Sets the [bold] and [hidden] flags ...
void enableFlags({bool? bold, bool? hidden}) {...}
```

I'm curious about the purpose of the question marks (`?`) after the data type (`bool`). Can someone provide an explanation of this syntax and clarify how it affects the function's behavior? Thank you!

Comment: This is covered in the same Dart Language Tour page that you linked to: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#important-concepts.  For even more details, see https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is with null safety, the question mark means that this bool? can possibly be null and flutter will allow you to assign null to it. String can never be null and you'll get an error before compiling.

It is a pretty big thing in Dart, so you better learn it from the [official documentation](https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety)